# Is there anything i can do about this dropdown being cutoff in IE9?

Tags: dropdown

I'm not incredibly experienced with sharepoint 2010 but I've never had a visual issue this drastic so far.  My dropdown list is getting cut off.

Did I do something wrong or is this a known issue?  The other thing I'm thinking is it's a case of Silverlight getting into a state that maybe a reboot would fix?

[image]

Comment: it's all just HTML that you are seeing there. If the option with the longest name was the first to load that may force things to load correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The dropdown will expand for the longest option in there ("Resolve ccake/EOM...") - guess its not an option to cut that down a little?

In that case then you can fix the width of the dropdown ([html select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)) using CSS.

You will have to use something like IE developer toolbar to figure out what css selector to use to target the dropdown - something like class or ID should do.

The standard way of adding CSS to an individual page is via the Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) - one example of how to do it -

[How to edit list forms in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/07/how-to-edit-list-forms-sharepoint-2010/)

Answer (score 1):

CSS should do the trick.

You should be looking for the class .ms-dlgFrameContainer and set it's overflow property to "auto"

eg

.ms-dlgFrameContainer {
    overflow:auto;
}

As the other poster mentioned above, you could just make the change using the CEWP, but I prefer to address the situation as a whole. If you are able to bind another CSS file to your master page then a global solution is the best way to go. If not, consider the option first specified.

Comment: nevermind... looks like I misread the question. My apologies.

Comment: You originally posted this comment as a second answer, and I have changed it to a comment for you. But if your answer no longer applies please just delete your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

None of this is Silverlight, so it's definetely not a Silverlight issue.

You can see by the presence of the scroll bar at the bottom that the dropdown is fitting to the full width of the option value. What's happening is the fixed width/position of the dialog itself constraining how much of the form you can see (and demanding horizontal scrolling).

Your only option would be to make the dialog larger, though that would potentially affect all of the dialog boxes in the environment. Think of the dialog as a fancy styled iframe, which you'll see if you hunt through the DOM and look at the structure. The dialog is a specific width, and the iframe fills the dialog. Like any iframe, if the content within it is larger than the dimensions of the iframe, it will induce scrolling (which is what you're seeing here).

You won't be able to inject CSS to change the dialog size on the form, since the form page is inside the iframe, and you need to control the dialog itself (on the original page). You could implement a global solution to change all of the dialog boxes, but one would argue that using more practical (ie shorter) options on the dropdown is a far easier solution.